# How do I find my coordinates (on Earth) using satellite information?

Tags: artificial-satellite

I was really interested in finding my own location using information from satellites, by using trilateration (so basically do what GPS are doing but by myself and with some math).

I don't really know if there's a website that could tell me the  latitude, longitude and altitude of a satellite.

Actually I found this website: https://in-the-sky.org/satmap_worldmap.php

So, at the end, I would have these 3 information pieces about 3 different satellites.

I was hoping to set equations with x,y and z but I don't know exacly how that would work.